# How to get eclipse project updated after adding extra maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a relative simple JAXRS Web Project with a pom.xml. I have done:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and then import the project to eclipse, and setup **Project Facets** and **Targeted Runtime** manually. So far everything works fine :)

Now, I have added an extra dependency to the pom.xml and run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

What should I do to get that dependency reflected in eclipse? Ideally I  would like to do it in a way I don't have to setup facets and runtime stuff again.

Comment: You could try right-click on your project>Maven>Update Project... ?

Comment: I don't have "Maven" in the menu. How do I get the "Maven" menu?

Comment: install `m2e` for eclipse from EclipseMarket

Comment: Then you should import your project as a Maven project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` is rather old.

The best way to work with Maven in Eclipse is the m2e Maven Integration. This is part of Eclipse for Java EE Developers, or JBoss Tools, or you can install it individually via **Help | Install new software** from the default Eclipse update site.

Comment: I see. I followed a tutorial that was too old. I have imported it as a Maven project and it works better :) Thanks!